# Manually enter and execute javascript statement in Firefox debugger

Tags: firefox, javascript-debugger

Using Firebug, I can manually enter a javascript statement and the debugger will execute it.  I can't find where/how to do so with Firefox debugger.

Can it be done?

(Sick and tired for Firebug quality going down the tubes.  Used to be the best debugger out there and it's a pile of crap now).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you type in commands in the console and if a javascript statement it will execute it.
About as intuitive as a football bat.